# Problem fitting luggage rack to bicycle

Tags: rack, luggage

I recently purchased a new bicycle, unfortunately I am struggling to fit the existing luggage rack I had to it.

The eyelets for connecting the rack to the bicycle are positioned below the top of the wheel, so unless the rack is positioned at a very severe angle (to the point the legs no longer reach the holes near the hub of the wheel) it will not fit.

On my previous bicycle the eyelets were much higher than the top of the wheel, so there was no problem at all.

Is there any way to get around this problem, or am I going to have to buy a new rack with the appropriate fitting?
I've uploaded two photographs to illustrate the problem:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVL6g.jpg
- https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASziJ.jpg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The front mounting straps on standard luggage racks are meant to be bent as needed to fit the bike.  It appears that bending them down just slightly and sliding them back in their slots should produce a nice alignment of the rack.

Comment: Looking at the pictures, this seems to be the right answer to the problem. +1